# rdfland rdfproc: adding a RDF literal

Tags: rdf, redland

In rdfproc/redland how can I add a typed literal ? The man page says:

```
   add-typed SUBJECT PREDICATE OBJECT OBJECT-LANG OBJECT-URI [CONTEXT]
          Add the triple with the datatyped literal object to the graph, in the optional Redland context if  CONTEXT  is given.
```

my rdf file:

```
$ xmllint test.rdf
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
</rdf:RDF>
```

I tried:

```
$ rdfproc  --storage file test.rdf  add-typed "http://my/subject" "http://my/predicate" "2015-50-17T15:50:00"  "fr" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"
```

but got the following error:

```
rdfproc: cannot have missing triple parts for add-typed
```

a simple 'add' works fine.

```
$ rdfproc  --storage file test.rdf  add "http://my/subject" "http://my/predicate" "2015-50-17T15:50:00"  && xmllint test.rdf
rdfproc: Added triple to the graph
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xml:base="file:///home/lindenb/path/test.rdf">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://my/subject">
    <ns0:predicate xmlns:ns0="http://my/">2015-50-17T15:50:00</ns0:predicate>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

version:

```
$ rdfproc -version
1.0.14
```

Comment: I don't know the tool you're using, but a datatyped literal doesn't have a language tag, so I don't think you should be specifying both "fr" and "xsd:dateTime", though I'm not sure what you'd replace "fr" with

Comment: yes I know about lang+type: but I tried many combinations., I tried the empty string but not "-". Checking: The ouput is now:  ` rdfproc --storage file test.rdf   add-typed "http://my/subject" "http://my/predicate" "2015-50-17T15:50:00"  "-" "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"
rdfproc: Warning - Model does not support contexts
rdfproc: Failed to add triple to the graph
`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify both language and datatype at the same time.

To omit either, supply `-` on the command line. For example:

```
rdfproc -n --storage sqlite test.sq add-typed "http://my/subject" "http://my/predicate" "2015-50-17T15:50:00" - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"
```

I changed the storage type to sqlite and added the option to create a new storage `-n` - the file storage produces another error `rdfproc: Warning - Model does not support contexts rdfproc: Failed to add triple to the graph` and I didn't read enough of the source to figure out how to fix that.

Comment: that doesn't work (v 1.0.16 ): `rdfproc: Warning - Model does not support contexts
rdfproc: Failed to add triple to the graph`

Comment: Yes - that's another problem. It works on some other storages.